# Why does JavaScript "window.postMessage" create duplicate messages?

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I'm trying to open a popup window, do some stuff, and send a message back to the opening window so I can do some more stuff with the data it sends.

Essentially, I'm adapting [the process outlined here](https://dev.to/dinkydani21/how-we-use-a-popup-for-google-and-outlook-oauth-oci).

This is my code on the "opening window". It runs when a social connect button is clicked. The code opens a popup window and assigns a listener event on the opening window to receive a message from the popup:

```
//Do the operation
let windowObjectReference = null;
let previousUrl = null;

const openSignInWindow = (url, name) => {

    // remove any existing event listeners
    window.removeEventListener('message', receiveMessage);

    // window features
    const strWindowFeatures =
        'toolbar=no, menubar=no, width=600, height=700, top=100, left=100';

    if (windowObjectReference === null || windowObjectReference.closed) {
        /* if the pointer to the window object in memory does not exist
         or if such pointer exists but the window was closed */
        windowObjectReference = window.open(url, name, strWindowFeatures);
    } else if (previousUrl !== url) {
        /* if the resource to load is different,
         then we load it in the already opened secondary window and then
         we bring such window back on top/in front of its parent window. */
        windowObjectReference = window.open(url, name, strWindowFeatures);
        windowObjectReference.focus();
    } else {
        /* else the window reference must exist and the window
         is not closed; therefore, we can bring it back on top of any other
         window with the focus() method. There would be no need to re-create
         the window or to reload the referenced resource. */
        windowObjectReference.focus();
    }

    // add the listener for receiving a message from the popup
    window.addEventListener('message', event => receiveMessage(event), false);

    // assign the previous URL
    previousUrl = url;

};


const receiveMessage = event => {
    // Do we trust the sender of this message? (might be different from what we originally opened, for example).
    if (event.origin !== websiteHomeUrlNoSlash) {
        return;
    }

    const { data } = event;
    console.log(data); //<--- THIS WHERE I'm SEEING DUPLICATES

};

//Invoke the function
openSignInWindow(url, name);
```

In the popup users login to their social account and then get redirected to a page on my app where the below code is run. The code posts a message back to the opening window and then closes the popup:

```
// Get the message data
const messageObj = {
    pluginReason: pluginReasonVar,
    displayName: displayNameVar,
    provider: providerVar,
};

if (window.opener) {
    // send them to the opening window
    window.opener.postMessage(messageObj, websiteHomeUrlNoSlash);
    // close the popup
    if (closePopup) {
        window.close();
    }
}
```

Everything *almost* works as expected. Users can login to their social accounts and all the redirections and opening and closing of the popup works fine.

**The Problem:**

If users go through the Social Connect process multiple times without refreshing the page, then the message data that is printed to the console is duplicated more and more each run.

**For example:**

- On the 1st run `console.log(data)` is printed once. So far this works as expected.
- On the 2nd run `console.log(data)` prints twice. It should only be printed once.
- On the 3rd run `console.log(data)` prints three times. It should only be printed once.

Each time the Social Connect process is run it should only print once. But somehow it's adding a duplicate copy on each subsequent run.

This duplication keeps growing until the users refreshes the page, which starts the count back at one.

I want to do more data manipulation at the point of the `console.log(data)` but I can't do that while it's creating duplicates copies on each subsequent run.

How do I stop that from happening?

Maybe it's because the listener event is not detaching? If so, how do I fix that?

Comment: I think you just need to {EventTarget}.removeEventListener() after the window close. otherwise you duplicate the listeners

Comment: The event listener is on the opening window, not the popup. Trying to remove it from the popup (where `window.close();` sits) just throws a ReferenceError because no event listener is defined on that window. Also I've already added a `window.removeEventListener('message', receiveMessage);` to the opening window. You can find it on the first line inside `openSignInWindow`. That should remove any existing event listeners on the opening window. Maybe the problem isn't the event listener not detaching but something else?

Comment: Consider using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API instead of the postMessage api, your problem will then go away by itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876900/2494754

Comment: Thanks but browser support for Broadcast Channel is 76.26% (https://caniuse.com/broadcastchannel) while Post Message is 96.29% (https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_window_postmessage). So in this case I need to go with Post Message because it has better support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have created an anonymous method `(event) => { }` as a wrapper and attached it to the `addEventListener` method.

```
window.addEventListener('message', event => receiveMessage(event), false);
```

It can't be removed by

```
window.removeEventListener('message', receiveMessage);
```

To fix it, make changes like this:

```
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);
```

Meanwhile, if the method `receiveMessage` gets lost every time the window has been closed, it's better to move the `removeEventListener` part inside the `receiveMessage`.

```
const receiveMessage = (event)=> {
  window.removeEventListener('message', receiveMessage);
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: I have commented out `window.addEventListener('message', event => receiveMessage(event), false);` inside `openSignInWindow` and replaced it with `window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);`. Unfortunately that did not fix the problem, I'm still getting duplicate `console.log` prints.

Comment: Might need some guidance on where exactly you want me to test placement of `window.receiveMessage = () => {};` but I have tested it underneath `window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);` and also directly above `openSignInWindow(oneAllDirectConnectUrl, windowName);`. Both locations still have the same problem of duplicate prints.

Comment: I deleted that one because I just realized it's a different `window` object. The direction is that the `receiveMessage` is a new method every time you launch a new window, even though it has the same name. so I am thinking if you can pass it in or store it somewhere in a global object, to make sure it's the same method everytime it should work.

Comment: by the way, is it an option to put `window.removeEventListener('message', receiveMessage);` inside your `receiveMessage` function?

Comment: Got it working! I replaced `window.addEventListener('message', event => receiveMessage(event), false);` with `window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);` as advised in your answer, and then I also added `window.removeEventListener('message', receiveMessage);` inside the `recieveMessage` function as advised in the comment above. Now it prints just one at a time each run :) If you edit your answer to include that last part I'll mark as accepted. Cheers!