# Can a service worker postMessage() directly to a shared worker client?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, postmessage, shared-worker

In a service worker, the [client interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client) has `postMessage()` for talking to clients, which can be of type `"window"`, `"worker"`, or `"sharedworker"`.

In `"window"` clients, the message event is sent to `navigator.serviceWorker.controller`. Example service worker code:

```
const windowClients = await clients.matchAll({ type: "window" });
windowClients[0].postMessage('Send this message to window.navigator.serviceWorker.controller');
```

But in shared worker clients, `navigator.serviceWorker` does not seem to exist. (This seems to change in a [draft spec](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#navigator-serviceworker). Edit: And [Safari](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_workernavigator_serviceworker).)

```
const sharedWorkerClients = await clients.matchAll({ type: "sharedworker" });
sharedWorkerClients[0].postMessage('Send this message to ???');
```

**So where is the message event dispatched in the shared worker?** Or is `postMessage()` a no-op here?

(There are workarounds like having the document transfer `SharedWorker#port` to the service worker. I'm wondering if there's a way to send messages directly.)

Comment: Try to use the Broadcast channel API instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel , with `self` instead of `navigator`

Comment: Good point about BroadcastChannel! Unfortunately I need to use the second "transferables" parameter to postMessage for my use case, so BroadcastChannel.postMessage doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, you can transfer only strings via BroadcastChannel `postMessage()`. Btw you can just use JSON.stringify(), and JSON.parse() on the other side? Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876900/2494754