# js popup open and check it's status on another page

Tags: javascript, html, popup

**open a popup window using window.open() on on html page**

```
pop=window.open('pops.html','mypop');
```

when i go to new page how can i detect whether this popup still opened or closed using java script. Thank you

Comment: "go to new page", what do you mean here? another website window?

Comment: go to another page of this web site by clicking a link :)

Comment: it's impossible, [here is a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905887/javascript-find-browser-windows-open-with-the-same-domain), opened windows are just belong to window.opener, not all windows with same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `window.opener.methodYouWantToCall()` to call methods in the window that opened the new window to talk to the opening window and tell it things like "I'm still open". you can read more [here](http://w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp). You will have to make sure that the method exists in the window though.
here is some pseudo code for how to handle it:

```
my_window = window.open(...);
my_window.opener.document.onUnload = function(){
my_window.opener.document.onload = function(){
my_window.opener.theWindow(a variable) = my_window;
}
};

(in new page):
function check(){
if(theWindow != null){
if(!theWindow.closed){
    // handle
}
} else {
setTimeout("check()", 1000);
}
}
```

Comment: no, i want check this from another page after going to another age on site

Comment: well as far as I know you can't make a variable that stays when you navigate away. You'll have to use `localStorage` or something.

Comment: why we can't use undefined or something for check this

Comment: Whatever works. It's your code you decide how you want to do it.

Comment: i found it :D   

     popup=window.open('','mypopup');;
        if (!popup|| popup.closed) {
            alert('closed');
           
        } else{
    
        alert('opened');
        }