# How can I send an event from child window to its parent window

Tags: javascript, tabs, postmessage, window.opener

My main goal is:

**Going to my application, open a link there in a new tab, make something in the new tab and send an event to the parent-main tab to refresh.**

I have learned 2 techniques that doesn't do exactly what I need:

1. postMessage - works as far as I know only on iframe and not on tabs
2. window.opener - works only with window.open(url) that opens only new window and not new tab.

How can I pass an event from the child to the parent using tabs? I'd be happy for a specific example for javascript code in the parent and the child. It should work for cross-domain (for example: www.mydomain.com and bills.mydomain.com).

Is there a a jQuery solution I am missing?

Comment: I believe `window.open` should return a new _Window_ object and if you're not running into problems with the same origin policy, you may be able to attach a listener from the parent onto this object or set an interval which checks for some variable.

Comment: @PaulS., It window.open does not open in new tab.

Comment: Actually users can decide if `window.open()`s are opened in the new tab or new window. There is a setting for this in browser's options.

Comment: It doesn't not work in chrome, but thanks for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works for me in chrome, firefox, ie(didn't test more browsers)

assume 3 documents

1. (**www.mydomain.com/parent.html**)the page that contains the 'main'-document with the link
2. (**bills.mydomain.com/child.html**)the page that will be opened by the link
3. (**www.mydomain.com/dispatcher.html**)explained later

at first set the domain-property of all 3 documents to mydomain.com

```
<script>
document.domain="mydomain.com";
</script>
```

in parent.html create a hidden iframe with a name-property of e.g. "hiddenframe". Also create some function that may later receive a response.

parent.html should now look like this:

```
<script>
document.domain="mydomain.com";
function fx(msg)//receives the response
{
  alert(msg)
}
</script>
<iframe name="hiddenframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
<a href="http://bills.mydomain.com/child.html" target="_blank">click</a>
```

---

In child.html you'll now be able to load a document into the hidden iframe inside parent.html

```
<script>
document.domain="mydomain.com";
window.open('http://www.mydomain.com/dispatcher.html','hiddenframe');
</script>
```

(don't be confused in face of the use of `window.open()` here, there will not open a new window, the page will be loaded into the iframe in parent.html)

---

In dispatcher.html you now may call the function inside parent.html

```
<script>
document.domain="mydomain.com";
parent.fx('you just got some response');
</script>
```

---

**When you only need to reload the parent.html it's a little bit easier.**

Again set the document.domain-property in parent.html and child.html(you don't need the iframe in parent.html and the dispatcher.html)

In parent.html also set the name-property of the window, e.g.

```
<script>
  window.name="parentTab";
</script>
```

In child.html you now may access the `parentTab`-window(tab)

```
<script>
    document.domain="mydomain.com";
    window.open('http://www.mydomain.com/parent.html','parentTab');
</script>
```

...or simply use "parentTarget" as target-property of a link or form in child.html

Answer (score 0):

What I did for myself, I implemeted some ajax to submit changes from the window2 into database. I implemeted JSON to pull new data from the database back to window1

Answer (score 0):

By seeing how [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/87359/1615483) only talk about `window.open` (which you don't want to use) and as afaik there is no easy way to [get all windows on the same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7905887/1615483), for what you want, you probably need to write your own framework to do this using [`window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage).
I don't think you'll get access to subdomains with it and definitely not to other domains, though.

---

Practical ideas for window-specific message passing using `sessionStorage`..
You can pass things in the URL (GET) so a way to pass messages could be to make the parent generate a unique id for itself `parentID`, a unique id for it's child `childID` (which is inserted into the URL along with the `parentID` on click if you're using an `<a>`, or a hidden field if you don't mind a `<form method="GET">`), then with `sessionStorage` save messages to the parent using keys like `parentID.childID.timeStamp`, have an interval in both parent and child that looks for `sessionStorage` *keys* starting with the window's ID, then a `.`, (i.e. the parent looks for `parentID.`) on a match copy the key & value to a new var, delete (so it doesn't get found again) and then parse as desired.

I know this is a bit wordy but I think it is likely much easier to explain as a concept than writing working example code.