# Send message between windows on same domain, no handle available

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to send a message between windows which were created independently of each other? That is, the user opened Window A somehow and then Window B somehow and now I would like to send a message from A -> B. The `postMessage` interface only works if I have a handle to the other window, which I do not. Both windows are on the same domain and I would know the exact URL of the other window.

*Note that I'm not looking for a solution which involves one window polling a value. I can already do that with localStorage and am looking for an alternative.*

Comment: It's an interesting question, which explains why it's not the first time it's asked. See [this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236828/javascript-make-tabs-windows-with-same-origin-communicate?rq=1). I don't think there is a cross-browser solution today.

Comment: I cannot imagine any other way than polling using cookies/localstorage. Browser extension perhaps?

Comment: The problem is that not everybody would agree on this being safe, even with a same origin policy, so I'm not sure you can expect this possibility in near future.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's impossible without polling.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905887/javascript-find-browser-windows-open-with-the-same-domain